# Deixar XML em una única linha

Tags: c#, xml, assinatura-digital

Minha aplicação em c# recebe o xml identado. Preciso deixar esse xml tudo em uma única linha. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você deve [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/126829/edit) sua pergunta e  adicionar mais detalhes, descreva qual e a mensagem de erro que está sendo exibida e insira o código do que tentou fazer  , tente criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas...

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Procure pontuar corretamente para que seja possivel o entendimento, e ser mais especifica ao explicar o problema, sinceramente eu nem consegui entender direito.

Comment: a solução está aqui: [Solução](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724940/is-there-any-way-to-save-an-xmldocument-without-indentation-and-line-returns) Obrigado

Comment: @novato, replica a resposta aqui mesmo, na sua pergunta, já marcando-a como resposta. Assim, algumas pessoas que não leem inglês conseguirão entender como resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Se você obtém o xml por um arquivo:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("arquivo.xml");
document.Save("arquivo2.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Ou se você tiver o xml em uma string:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(stringXML);
document.Save("arquivo.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode separar as linhas em array e depois concaternar

```
string xml = dadosdoxml.ToString();

var separar = xml.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string final = string.Join(" ", separar );
```

Comment: ainda não deu certo.... mas obrigado mesmo assim